# If I wanted to convert to Judaism, would I need to have my circumcision repeated?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah

I was baptized in the Catholic Church, raised in the Methodist Church, and became an atheist when I was about 14 years old.  My grandmother on my father's side was a non-observant Jew, but my father has always been Methodist.  I was circumcised as a baby, although I have no idea how long after birth it was done;  I assume it was performed by a doctor, but my mother says he was Italian, and probably Catholic, not Jewish. It certainly wasn't a bris, and the doctor obviously wasn't a moyle (excuse me if I misspelled the words).

I'm not planning to convert, but I am curious as to how my circumcision would be handled if I did convert.  Would the procedure need to be repeated by a moyle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally the circumcision preformed by a physician is sufficient to meet the physical requirements of "*milah*" (circumcision), nevertheless a process known as "*hatafas dam bris*" (הטפת דם ברית) is necessary (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 268:1). In this process the *Mohel* draws a ritual drop of blood from the place of circumcision for the sake of the covenant.  It is, or at least can be, painless. Insofar as most contemporary *mohelim* are unacquainted with adult circumcision, it is often the case that an uncircumcised convert will have the procedure preformed by a physician and subsequently have it "*kashered*" through *hatafas dam bris*.

Comment: i've had this done. Painless is not the word i would use x.x

Comment: Fair enough, but I have as well.

Comment: Is the blood taken from the foreskin, or the glans?  That would be a make or break issue for me.

Comment: There is no "foreskin" left if it is a case of hatafas dam bris, but it is done on the skin where the foreskin was removed from.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu TTBOMK it's a machloket acharonim if it's taken from where the foreskin had been attached or from the glans itself.